# Checking lock date

Tags: php

For some reason the test to see if if the current_time variable is bigger or smaller than the time to login is not right for some reason. I'm not sure what I'm missing. The lock_date property of the $user_data object stands for the exact datetime that the user made its last failed login attempt.
So its always continuing on with the code and by passing with the rest of the submit function.

I thought about switching the great than sign in the if statement when comparing the two times but with those two I didn't think it would make sense.

Anybody have any additional ideas?

```
$current_time = now();
$current_gmt_human_format = unix_to_human($current_time, TRUE, 'us');

/* Get user data from post username value */
$user_data = $this->users_model->get_by('username', $post_username);

if (count($user_data) > 0)
{
    /* User was found in database */

    if ($user_data->lock_date !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    {
        /* User is locked out */

        /* How long the user must wait to login */
        $wait_time = 60 * 15;

        /* Time user is able to login */
        $time_to_login = strtotime($user_data->lock_date) + $wait_time; 

        //echo 'current time is...' . $current_time;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo 'time to login is...' . $time_to_login;
        //die();

        if ($current_time < $time_to_login)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As per the request here is the data I have.

```
current readable format is...2013-05-23 08:03:44 PM
current time is...1369353824
user lock out...1369310405
wait time is...900
time to login is...1369311305
```

Comment: it would be cool to see some real data example. It could be a problem of DB and php time and timezone mismatch.

Comment: i posted some data for you to look at.

Comment: Something is wrong with your now() function. It returns unix timestamp that should not depend on timezone. So if i would run it on my local machine it should give me my current time. But it gives me the time in the future.

Comment: With codeigniter's now function you can use the config file to tell it either local or gmt and I have all my times to be used in the gmt zone. I thought about reversing the greater than sign but then that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Seems like now() function actually returns time in your local time zone (which is wierd because timestamp MUST be in GMT). Try to use time() instead. And it is interesting how you set lock_date in DB and what is the column type?

Comment: The column is a datetime field type as is the current datetime of the last failed login attempt.

Comment: now()

Returns the current time as a Unix timestamp, referenced either to your server's local time or GMT, based on the "time reference" setting in your config file. If you do not intend to set your master time reference to GMT (which you'll typically do if you run a site that lets each user set their own timezone settings) there is no benefit to using this function over PHP's time() function.

Comment: And how do you set lock_date? With now() function or using DB build in functions?

Comment: With use of the current_gmt_human_format from above. $this->users_model->lock_out_user($user_data->user_id, $current_gmt_human_format);

Comment: So maybe there is some conflict between codeigniter time functions and built in php functions. As lock_date was created with codeigniter function unix_to_human so when you convert it back to timestamp use human_to_unix() instead of strtotime().

Comment: I appreciate the idea. I tried your suggestion and for some reason it's doing the same thing as it was doing with the strtotime. I am going to stick with the human_to_unix function instead but still need to find out what is causing my issue still.

Comment: As far as I know all my logic is correct which doesn't make sense on why its not working.